# If a holomorphic bundle is smoothly trivial, is it holomorphically trivial?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

Let $E\rightarrow X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle which is smoothly trivial (i.e. $E$ has a smooth global frame). Can we say that $E$ is holomorphically trivial?

If yes, then what about the following generalization? If $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ are two holomorphic vector bundles over a complex manifold $X$ which are smoothly isomorphic, then they are holomorphically isomorphic.

If no, then does there exist an easy counterexample?

Comment: It's not true even  in the lowest possible dimension/rank, see this [MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/195555/is-there-a-toplogically-trivial-line-bundle-over-a-compact-riemann-surfaces-that)

Comment: The group of holomorphic line bundles over a genus $g$ Riemann surface  that are topologically trivial is a $(2g)$-dimensional Abelian variety, in particular isomorphic as a Lie group to $T^{2g}$.

Comment: It might be worth noting that while generally false this is true for Stein manifolds as was pointed out in a comment in this thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047523/why-is-every-holomorphic-line-bundle-over-mathbbc-trivial/2047551. The result is due to Grauert ( Analytische Faserungen über holomorph-vollständigen Räumen) https://eudml.org/doc/160618

Comment: Indeed, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299973/why-are-holomorphic-vector-bundles-over-mathbbcn-trivial/3408222#3408222) in the setting of bundles over Stein manifolds.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let $X$ be a paracompact topological space. Complex line bundles on $X$ are completely determined up to isomorphism by their first Chern class. More precisely, if $\operatorname{Vect}_1^{\mathbb{C}}(X)$ denotes the collection of isomorphism classes of complex line bundles on $X$, then $c_1 : \operatorname{Vect}_1^{\mathbb{C}}(X) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism. In particular, a complex line bundle $L$ is trivial if and only if $c_1(L) = 0$. If $X$ is a compact smooth manifold, isomorphism classes of topological complex line bundles coincide with isomorphism classes of smooth complex line bundles.

Now let $X$ be a complex manifold. The collection of isomorphism classes of holomorphic line bundles on $X$ has a group structure given by tensor product (the inverse is dual). This group is called the Picard group and denoted $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$. A transition functions argument shows that $\operatorname{Pic}(X) \cong H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*)$. Associated to any complex manifold, we have a short exact sequence of sheaves

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\times 2\pi i} \mathcal{O} \xrightarrow{\exp}\mathcal{O}^* \to 0$$

called the exponential sequence. The long exact sequence in cohomology gives

$$\dots \to H^1(X, \mathcal{O}) \to H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(X, \mathcal{O}) \to \dots$$

The map $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is the composition of the isomorphism $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*) \to \operatorname{Pic}(X)$ with the first Chern class. As $H^k(X, \mathcal{O}) \cong H^{0,k}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)$, we see that

- if $h^{0,1} = 0$, the map $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is injective, and
- if $h^{0,2} = 0$, the map $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is surjective.

In particular, if $h^{0, 1} > 0$, the map $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$ may have non-trivial kernel (in fact, it necessarily does, see the discussion below the line). That is, there could be a non-trivial holomorphic line bundle $L$ with $c_1(L) = 0$, i.e. a holomorphic line bundle which is smoothly trivial.

The simplest example of a complex manifold with $h^{0,1} > 0$ is a genus one Riemann surface which has $h^{0,1} = 1$. An explicit non-trivial holomorphic line bundle is $\mathcal{O}(x_0 - x_1)$ with $x_0, x_1$ distinct points of the surface. It has first Chern class zero so it is smoothly trivial, but it is not holomorphically trivial as it has no global holomorphic sections other than the zero section: a non-zero section would have associated divisor $x_0 - x_1$ but this is impossible as divisors associated to holomorphic sections are always effective.

---

By investigating the long exact sequence more carefully, we can see how many holomorphic line bundles have first Chern class zero and hence are smoothly trivial; we denote the collection of isomorphism classes of such line bundles by $\operatorname{Pic}^0(X)$.

$$\dots \to H^0(X, \mathcal{O}) \to H^0(X, \mathcal{O}^*) \to H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(X, \mathcal{O}) \to H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to \dots$$

Note that $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}) \cong \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}) = \mathcal{O}(X)$ is the collection of holomorphic functions on $X$, and $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}^*) \cong \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}^*)$ is the collection of nowhere-zero holomorphic functions on $X$. If $X$ is compact, the only holomorphic functions are constant functions, so $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}) \cong \mathbb{C}$, $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}^*) \cong \mathbb{C}^*$ and the map $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}) \to H^0(X, \mathcal{O}^*)$ is nothing but the exponential map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^*$. As this is surjective, $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}^*) \to H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is the zero map, and hence $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(X, \mathcal{O})$ is injective.

By exactness, the kernel of $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is precisely the image of $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}) \to H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*)$ which is isomorphic to the quotient of $H^1(X, \mathcal{O})$ by the kernel. Again by exactness, the kernel of this map is equal to the image of the map $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(X, \mathcal{O})$ which is isomorphic to $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})$ as the map is injective. Therefore, if $X$ is compact,

$$\operatorname{Pic}^0(X) \cong \frac{H^1(X, \mathcal{O})}{H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})}$$

which is a complex torus of dimension $h^{0,1}$.

Comment: There is another simple example of a holomorphically non-trivial (rank $2$) vector bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^1$ which is smoothly trivial. Consider the natural projection $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}^4 \to S^2$, as a smoothly trivial real vector bundle over $S^2$. One can define a structure of a rank $2$ holomorphic vector bundle in $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}^4$, and a complex structure on $S^2$, that would make the above map a holomorphic bundle map over $\mathbb{C}P^1$. More specifically, one can define a holomorphic rank $2$ bundle which is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(1)+\mathcal{O}(1)$.

Comment: This is known as the twistor space of flat hyperkähler space $\mathbb{H}$ (the space of quaternions, viewed as a hyperkähler space). Its description can be found in many expository papers on twistor theory. The $S^2$ represents the natural sphere of complex structures one can put on $\mathbb{H}$; it is the unit sphere in imaginary quaternionic space. Thus over each $x \in S^2$, one endows the fibre $\mathbb{R}^4$ over that point $x$ with the corresponding complex structure $I_x$. This is basically how you define the holomorphic bundle structure on $S^2\times \mathbb{R}^4$ that I have mentioned

Comment: Very beautiful answer