# Why is every holomorphic line bundle over $\mathbb{C}$ trivial?

Tags: complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

Why is every holomorphic line bundle over $\mathbb{C}$ necessarily trivial?

I am having a hard time finding a proof to this seemingly innocuous fact.

I have tried showing that such a line bundle will have a nowhere-zero global section (this is one of the few criterion I currently have at my disposal for showing a line bundle is trivial).

I would much appreciate either a link to a proof of this statement or a hint of how I could prove this myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $X$ be a complex manifold and denote by $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$ the Picard group of $X$ which is the collection of isomorphism classes of holomorphic line bundles on $X$ with binary operation given by tensor product and the isomorphism class of the trivial bundle serves as the identity element. By considering transition functions, one can show that $\operatorname{Pic}(X) \cong H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*)$ (as groups).

The exponential sheaf sequence

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}^* \to 0$$

gives rise to a long exact sequence in cohomology

$$\dots \to H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(X, \mathcal{O}) \to H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to \dots$$

Now consider the case $X = \mathbb{C}$. As $\mathbb{C}$ is contractible, $H^1(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ and $H^2(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$. Therefore,

$$\operatorname{Pic}(\mathbb{C}) \cong H^1(\mathbb{C}, \mathcal{O}^*) \cong H^1(\mathbb{C}, \mathcal{O}) \cong H^{0,1}_{\bar{\partial}}(\mathbb{C})$$

where the last isomorphism is given by Dolbeault's Theorem.

The final piece of the puzzle is the following non-trivial fact: for any smooth function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}$, there is a smooth function $u$ such that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \bar{z}} = f$. As any $(0,1)$-form on $\mathbb{C}$ is of the form $f d\bar{z}$, we see that all $(0, 1)$-forms are $\bar{\partial}$-exact: $f d\bar{z} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial \bar{z}} d\bar{z} = \bar{\partial}u$. Therefore, $H^{0,1}_{\bar{\partial}}(\mathbb{C}) = 0$ and hence every holomorphic line bundle on $\mathbb{C}$ is trivial.

Comment: Right. Grauert (Analytische Faserungen über holomorph-vollständigen Räumen) proved a much more general result (Oka-Grauert principle) that the classification of holomorphic bundles over Stein manifolds coincides with their smooth classification.

Comment: @Michael Albanese This is essentially equivalent to what you have written, but you can also phrase the last part as follows. If you have reduced the problem to the vanishing of $H^1(\mathbb{C}, \mathcal{O})$ then the vanishing of this group is clear: $\mathbb{C}$ is a domain of holomorphy, and therefore Stein, and $\mathcal{O}$ is a coherent analytic sheaf. It is then by Cartan's Theorem B that $H^1(\mathbb{C}, \mathcal{O})=0$.