# How can it be that the Chern class fully determines a line bundle, but having Chern class zero doesn't imply a line bundle is trivial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, characteristic-classes

It is well-known that the [Chern class of a line bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern_class#The_Chern_class_of_line_bundles) in $H^2(M,\mathbb Z)$ fully determines the bundle up to isomorphism. However, in [this wikipedia entry on Calabi-Yau manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold#Definitions) it is stated that there are manifolds that have a non-trivial canonical bundle, but a vanishing integral Chern class.

What is happening here? The only thing I can think of is that a differentiably trivial line bundle doesn't have to be holomorphically trivial. Is that the case? How should one think of such bundles that are topologically but not analytically trivial?

Comment: The Chern classes of a bundle of dimension $\ge2$ don't necessarily determine it up to isomorphism.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I know, but in dimension 1 apparently not either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a holomorphic bundle is smoothly trivial, is it holomorphically trivial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875037/if-a-holomorphic-bundle-is-smoothly-trivial-is-it-holomorphically-trivial)

Comment: In my previous comment "dimension" should be "rank".

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown In mine too ;)

Comment: Chern class is slightly vague unless you say where it takes values. Chern class can take values in $\mathbb{Z}$ and then for curves, it just computes the degree. It can also take values in the Chow group and then it determines the line bundle in any dimension.

Comment: @Mohan Ok, I'll edit to clarify

Comment: I do not know what you mean by `how to think of bundles which are differentially trivial, but not holomorphically'. These exist, as I said, since integral Chern class computes just the degree for a curve and there are many degree zero non-trivial line bundles. If you look at the proof of their triviality in the differential category, it will come down to having partition of unity in that category and not in the analytic category.

Comment: @Mohan Does that mean that divisors of the same degree on a curve give diffeomorphic line bundles, even if the divisors are not linearly equivalent?

Comment: Yes, linear equivalence is a holomorphic condition in the usual situation.