# Why are holomorphic vector bundles over $\mathbb{C}^n$ trivial?

Tags: complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

Let $E$ be a holomorphic vector bundle over $\mathbb{C}^n$.

How do I show that $E$ is trivial?

I know this to be true for vector bundles over affine varieties but I don't know how to extend the proofto holomorphic vector bundles.

Comment: Perhaps because $\Bbb C^n$ is contractible?

Comment: Right. But how do I use this to fact to prove triviality?

Comment: In many categories, bundles of this-or-that type are characterized as pullbacks of some universal bundle over some classifying space. I don't know whether this is the case for "holomorphic bundles", but it seems likely. Anyhow, in this setting, different isomorphism classes of bundles over $X$ correspond to different homotopy-classes of maps from $X$ into that classifying space.  Now...how many homotopy classes of maps from $\Bbb C^n$ to your classifying space are there?

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer?

Comment: As Moishe Kohan's answer below indicates, every holomorphic vector bundle on a contractible Stein manifold is trivial. However, there are contractible non-Stein manifolds which admit non-trivial holomorphic vector bundles, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/165210/21564).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, indeed, one way to argue is that ${\mathbb C}^n$ is contractible, which implies that all complex vector bundles over ${\mathbb C}^n$ are smoothly trivial. The second piece of information is the **Oka-Grauert Principle**, see for instance Theorem 5.3.1 in

F. Forstneric, Stein Manifolds and Holomorphic Mappings, Springer Verlag, 2011.

According to the Oka-Grauert Principle, the classification of holomorphic vector bundles over Stein manifolds (and ${\mathbb C}^n$ is Stein) is equivalent to their classification as smooth bundles. Putting these two things together, you conclude that every holomorphic vector bundle over ${\mathbb C}^n$ is (holomorphically) trivial.

Comment: I wonder why this perfect answer (that I just discovered) has not been upvoted before. This would certainly also have amazed Immanuel Kant.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Yes, I think OP is still thinking about what to think of my answer.